# How to use separate proxy settings for incognito mode under Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, proxy

According to [this reported issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=509) Chromium supports separate proxy settings for incognito. However, when I try to edit the proxy settings, I get a page that says this:

> When running Chromium under a supported desktop environment, the
>   system proxy settings will be used. However, either your system is not
>   supported or there was a problem launching your system configuration.
>
> But you can still configure via the command line. Please see man chromium-browser for more information on flags and environment
>   variables.

Is there some way to set separate proxy settings for incognito from the command line that will still apply when incognito is launched from in the browser? Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1):

This Chrome extension lets you configure a proxy just for incognito mode:
https://github.com/pmarks-net/incognito-proxy

The relevant API call is
`chrome.proxy.settings.set({scope: 'incognito_persistent', value: ...})`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368515/how-to-see-the-proxy-settings-on-windows

chrome://net-internals/#proxy
Enter this in the address bar of Chrome.